# When should I use Memcached vs adding a column to the database?

Tags: database, caching, database-design, memcached, relational-database

I'd like to track the last date each user of my application has visited a certain page. One way to do this would be to add a column to the users table in my database, and update it every time the user visits the page. An alternative method would be to store this data in Memcached for each user.

I realized that I was favoring the Memcached solution, but for reasons that don't *seem* legitimate:

- The users table has lots of columns already, and I don't want to add to that unnecessarily.
- It's easier to use Memcached than it is to add a table to the db by creating a migration, etc.

So what *is* the appropriate choice here? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached can be used to store arbitrary data with a limit life cycle, but shouldn't be used as database replacement.

The appropriate choice would be to create an isolated database table for this specific business logic. As this feature will introduce many writes, it would be important not to lock any other tables that might have other core functionality (like your user table.) Naturally, said feature will effect database I/O; in which, Memcached would be ideal in storing a queue of data to be handled by a batch process.

**Very basic outline of a Memcached queue**

Following [Memcached's protocol](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L56), your application can easily maintain a queue list of affected users, and set/replace meta-data related to a specific user.

```
/* Application handling Memcached Queue */

[ User is in Queue ? ]________ no 
 |                             |
 | yes                        [ Append user to queue list ]
 |                             |
[ Replace user data ]         [ Set user date ]
```

A daily, or hourly, process should be able to digest the queue list, and write the user's meta-data to the database.